# Ubuntu and web server permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I,

I am going to ask a question that has already been posted many times but even though I have read many guides and posts, I still have doubts.

I have a server with ubuntu 14.04 on which I have a user with sudo permissions (secondary group "sudo") and a user who just want to use for the "web server".

I explain in detail...

- My webserver user is "jack" and this is part of the group www-data (as the primary group)
- The virtual hosts point to the jack's home directory where I created a subfolder called "alias" which contains subfolders with the various sub-domains

es.

> /home/jack/public_html <-- main site
>
> /home/jack/alias/forum <-- subdomain
>
> /home/jack/alias/wiki  <-- subdomain
>
> /home/jack/alias/cloud <-- subdomain

what I would like to know is:

-**first question**-

is correct that jack belongs to the primary group www-data instead of belonging to the group users, and as a secondary group www-data ?

-**second question**-

a friend advised me to set the permissions on the web server folder in this way

> chgrp www-data /home/jack/public_html
>
> chmod g+rwxs /home/jack/public_html

and the same for the alias folders.
Now it seems to work but there is a problem....

-if i load a file in the web server root permits are

**jack:www-data 0644**

-if the files are generated by www-data (for example through a cms)

**www-data:www-data 0666**

Now, if I edit a file manually, for example via ftp, this changes the permissions and creates problems to the various "web app"

how can I do to fix it?

Thanks for reading
Regards,
Fabio

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You will probably get better expertise on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).